# Vue Router Child, Trailing slash

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Is is it normal behavior for Vue to add a trailing slash to the default child subroute?

For example:

*URL*

```
Result:
/#/user/test/
```

*Link*

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'user', params: { username: 'test' } }">Test User Overview</router-link>
```

*Routes*

```
routes: [
     {
        path: '/user/:username',
        component: User,
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                name: 'user',
                component: UserOverview
            },
            {
                path: 'stats',
                name: 'user.stats',
                component: UserStats
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I would expect the *user* link to have the path specified by its parent, meaning without a trailing slash. Like this: `/#/user/test`. If its normal behavior, can I somehow prevent it?

Comment: This solution solved my problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/58132290/4801486

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is. And do not try to prevent this behaviour, it is preferred and recommended.

Read more in this article - it is older, but not outdated: https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2010/04/to-slash-or-not-to-slash.html?m=1

Comment: Thanks for the link. However, in [this](https://jsfiddle.net/yyx990803/L7hscd8h/) example provided by Vue, they explicitly link without `/`. See `/user/foo`.

Comment: Thanks, I do see the potential conflicts.

Comment: @FredrikL Glad to help