# Why router link have diferent behavior in mobil view?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

When I use router links in desktop view works fine but in mobile view the links lack the "/"  to work, any idea to make it work for mobile (I mean when max-width change) (bootstraps makes all the jobs). I think a parameter or something to keep it working if bootstraps changes to a copy the menu adapted to mobile screen. In that swap of styles bootstrap stripes the "/" to the links with router vue link to. Any advice, suggerence or sample link will appretiated.

Comment: Any code examples, versions or codepen / jsfiddles will be appreciated too :)

Answer (score 0):

You should read this.
[Vue Router Child, Trailing slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47350259/vue-router-child-trailing-slash)

Also to prevent this you can use strict in vue-router as follows

```
const route1 = { template: '<div>Route 1 (strict)</div>' }
const route2 = { template: '<div>Route 2 (no strict)</div>' }
```

Check the fiddle link
http://jsfiddle.net/L7hscd8h/9377/